# Send button click event from iOS Today Widget without launching the host app

Tags: ios, swift3, today-extension, ios8-today-widget

I am writing a Today Widget for an iOS app. The widget has a few action buttons. I want to receive the click event when someone clicks on it. However, **it should not launch the app**.

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365315/perform-action-in-host-app-from-today-extensionwidget-without-opening-app-ios) but to no avail.

My current implementation is to define a URL Scheme, and call openURL on those button presses like so:

> Button 1 links to myApp://button1
>
> Button 2 links to myApp://button2
>
> Button 3 links to myApp://button3

I am receiving these events in the AppDelegate's

> [application(_:open:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application#parameters)

Here's the Code in TodayWodgetController

```
@IBAction func widgetClicked(sender: UIButton){
    if sender == button1 {
        let u = NSURL(string: "myApp://button1")
        self.extensionContext?.open(u! as URL, completionHandler: nil)            
    }
    ...
}
```

and here is the code I'm using in the host app's AppDelegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                          open url: URL,
                          options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    
    if url.absoluteString.range(of: "button1") != nil{
        print ("Button 1 Pressed")
    }

    ....

    return true
    
}
```

However, like I said, it also launches the host App. I want it to just send me the click event without launching the App.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that from an app extension.

Definition of `open(_ URL: URL, completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)` as described by **Apple**:

> Asks the system open a URL on behalf of the currently running app
>   extension.
>
> Each extension point determines whether to support this method, or
>   under which conditions to support this method. In iOS 8, only the
>   Today extension point (used for creating widgets) supports this
>   method.
>
> **Important: Apple allows a widget to use the open(_:completionHandler:) method to open the widget’s own containing
>   app.**